# nock: how to mock requests with additional headers? I'm getting Nock: No match for request

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nock

I make the following request with Axios:

```javascript
axios.get("http://request.url/app.php", {
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "X-Application-Key": "my-api-key",
  },
  params: {
    url: "http://some/url",
    format: "json",
    param1: 1,
    param2: 99999,
  },
});
```

Heres the mock:

```javascript
const myAPI = nock("http://request.url/");

myAPI
  .get("/app.php")
  .query(({url}) => url === "http://some/url")
  .replyWithFile(200, path.resolve(__dirname, "my-response.json"), {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  });
```

Everything works fine as long as the `X-Application-Key` is not present in the request. When the `X-Application-Key` header is present then I get the following error from nock:

```
Error: Error: Nock: No match for request {
  "method": "OPTIONS",
    "url": "<request url goes here>",
    "headers": {
    "origin": "http://localhost",
      "access-control-request-method": "GET",
      "access-control-request-headers": "X-Application-Key",
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (darwin) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/11.12.0",
      "host": "<my host goes here>",
      "content-length": 0
  }
}
```

I know it has something to do with the OPTIONS request, but I have no idea how to get around this issue.

I tried to use `.matchHeader()` methods in a following way:

```javascript
myAPI
  .get("/app.php")
  .matchHeader("Accept", () => true)
  .matchHeader("X-Mashape-Key", () => true)
  .query(({url}) => url === "http://some/url")
  .replyWithFile(200, path.resolve(__dirname, "my-response.json"), {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  });
```

But it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It has nothing to do with nock. It was an issue on the Axios end. It turned out that I have to use the `axios/lib/adapters/http` adapter when calling Axios in node environment.

So the solution is to initialize Axios this way:

```typescript
import * as httpAdapter from "axios/lib/adapters/http";

const axios = Axios.create({
  adapter: httpAdapter,
  // Other options
});
```